# Change classes when a string is received on rxjs stream

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have a stream that emits a string.
Depending on this string I want to add the following classes to a tag:

- "ok" -> fa-check
- "loading -> fa-spin fa-spinner
- "error" -> fa-times

I was experimenting with [class.className] in angular2 but I am not having any success.

```
@Component({
    selector: '[event-spinner]',
    template: `
            <i class="fa fa-2x" [class.fa-spinner]="icon == 'loading'" id="spin"></i>
  `
  // the following doesn't work as well
  //directives: [NgClass],
  //template: `
  //<div class="col-xs-5">
  //  <i class="fa fa-2x" [ngClass]="{'fa-check': icon == 'ok', 'fa-spin': icon == 'loading', 'fa-spinner': icon == 'loading', 'fa-times': icon == 'error'}" id="spin"></i>
  //</div>
  //`
})
export class EventSpinner {
    icon: string = "ok";

    constructor(public eventsService: EventsService) {
        //eventsService.icons.subscribe((x) => {
        //    this.icon = x;
        //});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
    selector: '[event-spinner]',
    template: `
<i class="fa fa-2x" [ngClass]="{'fa-check': icon == 'ok', 'fa-spin': icon == 'loading', 'fa-spinner': icon == 'loading', 'fa-times': icon == 'error'}" id="spin"></i>
  `
})
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WpUzvor8Ulf4Xje2D7Hf?p=preview)

Comment: I have used your solution (see updated question) but I get the following error:
`EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`

Comment: I added a Plunker example. You have to open browser devTools and find the `<i>` element to see the effect.

Comment: ok thanks, I definetely have some other error in my app. thanks!